# Android studio VCS integration

Tags: version-control, android-studio

I'm trying to setup a VCS, in Android studio, to sync my android project between my desktop and my laptop. But it's not looking an intuitive procedure for a noob.

Can someone tell me the exactly steps I need to do?

I'd like to add a remote private Bitbucket repository (mercurial preferred over git), and push/pull changes using Android studio GUI. That's all, no branch, no merge, just a simple sync of java source files and xml resource files.

Is this possible?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I get occasional upvotes for this answer, so a bit of clarification is needed. The original answer was written, and true, when AS was in beta, before the 1.0 release. Nowdays, as of AS 1.1.0, the VCS integration is included in the IDE out of the box.
It works directly with both Bitbucket, Github (git and mercury) and some other VCS:es. So there is no need to play around with plugins for that. Just use the VCS menu and find what you need.

Old outdated answer:
*Im regularily using the bitbucket plugin. To install it download the BitBucket plugin. In Android studio
File->Settings->Plugins and Install plugin from disk where you choose the entire plugin zip. That installs it without fuzz on win 8.*

Answer (score 9):

Try the bitbucket plugin: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6207?pr=androidstudio
In general, for anything that is a generic IDE function (not specific to Android), you can simply follow IntelliJ's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In Android studio

> File->Settings->Plugins

Enable `Enable Subversion Integration` checkbox and `Apply`

Then, Restart Android Studio and SVN will be integrated